# Как правильно обрабатывать не отслеживаемые файлы в Git

Tags: git

Есть проект в котором часть файлов отслеживаемая, другая нет (например картинки), при этом всём они образуют полностью рабочую систему. Но возникает такая ситуация, когда надо что-то доработать. Создается новая ветка, делаются изменения. Но если происходит переход между ветками, то все не отслеживаемые файлы до этого стираются, т.е. нельзя вернуться к изначальному состоянию origin когда там были и локальные и отслеживаемые файлы (картинки пропали). Как правильно обрабатывать такие ситуации, чтоб не возникало потерь данных? Я еще учусь и экспериментирую, поэтому было бы очень полезно, чтоб мне посоветовали профессиональный правильный подход, спасибо.

Comment: если файлы должны меняться при переходе между ветками - их надо отслеживать, вот и всё

Comment: добавь их в .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

Вы чего-то не договариваете. Гит не удаляет неотслеживаемые файлы при переключении веток. Разве что, если вы их добавили в какой-то ветке в репозиторий а затем удалили. Тогда при переключении на такую ветку файлы, конечно, удалятся.

Но правильно занести все такие файлы в игнор, чтобы случайно не задеть гитом. И чтобы он их не видел в статусе.